# Formatting the output with proper paranthesis - Prolog (without using ! and --> )

Tags: prolog

I have the same question as the [formatting the output with proper paranthesis - Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64369051/formatting-the-output-with-proper-paranthesis-prolog) but the solution should not use `!`  and `-->`. The accepted answers from the link has both of these operators. Especially I am looking for a solution using Prolog pattern matching on a rule's parameters.

For convenience sake I am rewriting the question here.

This question is directly related to [first order logic creating terms for arithmetic expressions using prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325939/first-order-logic-creating-terms-for-arithmetic-expressions-using-prolog). After implementing the logic as per the link I have issues with the formatting of the ourput for `printauth/1`. It currently results as `8-2+4* -3`, how is it possible to get something like `((8-2)+(4* -3))` (notice its not the same as `+(-(8,2),*(4,-3)))`.

I have been trying to using various options `(\k,\q)` in `format/2` predicate but nothing works. even I tried `write_canonical` and other write predicates, still no success.

I understand that I am not able modify the output because of `=..`  predicate.

```
arithmetic_operator(plus, +).
arithmetic_operator(minus, -).
arithmetic_operator(times, *).

arithmetic_expression(N, N) :- integer(N).

arithmetic_expression(Term, Expr) :-
    Term =.. [Functor,Component1,Component2],
    arithmetic_operator(Functor, Operator),
    arithmetic_expression(Component1, Expr1),
    arithmetic_expression(Component2, Expr2),
    Expr =.. [Operator, Expr1, Expr2].
```

```
printterm(Term) :- arithmetic_expression(Term, Expr), format("(~w\n)",[Expr]).
```

current output

```
?- printterm(plus((minus(8,2)),(times(4,3)))).
(8-2+4*3)
true .
```

Expected output

```
?- printterm(plus((minus(8,2)),(times(4,3)))).
((8-2)+(4*3))
true .
```

Comment: You can remove and convert the DCG syntax following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993566/is-there-a-way-or-an-algorithm-to-convert-dcg-into-normal-definite-clauses-in-pr if you remove cuts you will have choice points

Comment: @damianodamiano I am not sure how this helps in this case.

Comment: You are not showing any real effort on solving this yourself.

Comment: I suggest posting a [mcve]. This would require you to figure what parts are not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think focusing on I/O like this is the right way to go. The linked answer builds the parenthesized expression as a data structure, which can use nice features like DCGs (the `-->` rules).

That said, if you must, you can print fully parenthesized expressions in Prolog like in any other programming language: Using recursion.

```
print_term(Term) :-
    arithmetic_expression(Term, Expr),
    print_expr(Expr),
    nl.

print_expr(N) :-
    integer(N),
    write(N).
print_expr(Expr) :-
    Expr =.. [Operator, Left, Right],
    write('('),
    print_expr(Left),
    write(Operator),
    print_expr(Right),
    write(')').

?- print_term(plus((minus(8,2)),(times(4,3)))).
((8-2)+(4*3))
true ;
false.
```